# Use of "I called myself" + gerund/participle

Tags: grammar, expressions, colloquialisms, origin-unknown

Is anyone familiar with this construction and its origin? Is it standard or non-standard?

> "I called myself taking a nap but ended up sleeping half the day."
>
> "I called myself cooking dinner, but I burnt the chicken."

I grew up hearing this from elders but have never seen it written in anything published.

Comment: I've never heard it -- but if you google "I called myself taking a nap," you get a number of responses.  It's dialect, for sure.

Comment: I suspect you're mis-hearing *I **caught** myself [doing something I wouldn't normally do]*.

Comment: No, its definitely "called myself".

Comment: Can this be interpreted as standard english? You can say "I called myself a writer even though I never published anything."  This construction just substitutes a gerund, as in "I called myself winning the race, but ..."

Comment: I've never heard it. Which country is it from? Which culture uses it?

Comment: I'm American. I've only heard it here, mostly from older people, usually southern.

Comment: Are there any rules that forbid using a gerund as an objective complement? That's essentially what the construction is doing.

Comment: Is it generally used in the form you've listed, i.e. "I called myself <planned action>, but <some unplanned result>"? Is it possible that "called" is actually clipped speech for "recalled", or at least derived over time from clipping of the "re"? The speaker may be relating how they **remember** (recalled) starting/planning an activity, but it didn't turn out the way they planned.

Comment: Google "I called myself taking a nap."  You'll find lots of examples.

Answer (score 4):

Harold Wentworth, *American Dialect Dictionary* (1944) has an entry for "call oneself" that is quite localized—three examples from West Virginia, and one in a short story by William Faulkner that Wentworth assigns to Mississippi. Here is the full entry, with examples:

> **call oneself.** To think that one (is doing something); also to pretend that one (is doing something);—usu. followed by a pres ptc.
>
> [Examples:] **1930s w[astern] W[est] V[irgini]a Berkeley Co[unty]** 'What do you call yourself a-doin'?' = What do you think you're doing?, What are you doing?, What would you say you're doing there? **1939 n[orthern] W[est] V[irgini]a Morgantown** *Negro* 'I call myself making better gravy' = (I think that) my gravy making is improving. **1943 Mississippi** A 70-year-old man ... squatting all night on a hill & calling himself listening to  a fox race that he couldn't even hear. W. Faulkner 'Shingles.' **1943 n[orthern] W[est] V[irgini]a Star C[ity]** *Negro* 'Look at him callin' himself.' Said of a dog bristling & scratching the ground at the sight of another dog.

The wording "call [oneself]" does appear to be peculiar to U.S. Southern dialect—specifically to parts of West Virginia and (maybe) Mississippi. Strikingly, in the poster's two examples above, the sense of "called myself" seems to be "intended," whereas in Wentworth's examples from the 1930s and 1940s its sense is closer to "thought," "pretended," or "claimed." I would be very interested to know where the poster has heard the expression used in recent years.

Answer (score 2):

I found something, but I'm not sure how relevant it is to the nap.  Still, it might be progress, and it's a bit long for a comment.

http://www.yourdictionary.com/call

Our Living Language African American Vernacular English uses *call oneself* with a present participle, as in "They call themselves dancing," to express the idea that the people being talked about are not very good at what they're doing (in this case, dancing), even though they may think they are. This construction has a structure and meaning similar to the Standard English use of call oneself with a noun phrase or adjective, as in He calls himself a dancer or She calls herself intelligent.